# Trouble trying to make a bootable USB on Rufus

Tags: rufus

I am trying to make a bootable USB drive using Rufus.  I downloaded Ubuntu on my laptop.  I opened up Rufus and for Boot selection the only options I have are, "Non bootable"  "FreeDOS" and "Disk or ISO image (please select)"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you selected Device? (Target USB), Have you selected the ISO file? (click SELECT), Have you selected Partition Scheme? (MBR or GPT). Have you checked ISO's MD5SUM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"(please select)"* means you need to click on the <kbd>SELECT</kbd> button in Rufus to select the Ubuntu ISO you have downloaded.

In case this is what you expect, Rufus does not "guess" that you've just downloaded an ISO and that it should use that (since it would require monitoring downloads which would be a huge invasion of privacy). Instead you need to tell Rufus, through the browse dialog that opens after you click <kbd>SELECT</kbd>, what ISO you actually want to use.

**Then** you should be able to just click <kbd>START</kbd> in Rufus.